# Command line media catalog for some backup dvds - is there such a thing?

Tags: backup, media, organizer-software

I'm looking for a command line application (really simple, that uses only text files for storage) that can catalog my backup dvds. Something similar to WhereIsIt, but using command line.

Suppose I have 10 dvds, each one with a lot of files. I would like to "catalog" these dvds to a lot of text files, and, when needing to search for a file inside these dvds, instead of checking all dvds, I would just search the catalog.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you want to do?

Comment: @Joe Internet: Done.

Comment: So you only want to keep a list of the file names, then if you need file abc.xyz, you'll search for that file name in the text file catalog?

Comment: @Joe Internet: Yep. I know I can use 10 lines of bash script to do it, using only (like find . * > /home/user/catalog1), but I would like to know if anyone did something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think this is indeed to simple to have an "application". Just using grep find and the shell itself I can accomplish what I want. I'm going through that route.

Comment: can you give some examples to make a catalog for off-line search? something like `ls -lR > catalog.txt` ?

Comment: @meduz Actually, you can use a binary called `tree` and do `tree /media/my_media/ > ~/Desktop/catalog.txt`, since you can have a lot of subfolders.